# Save facebook webpage after user authorization using PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

After I login facebook I want to save the content of https://www.facebook.com/pages (no specific page id but the url as you see it, and see suggested Favorite Pages, not pages I like or selected)

I am not trying to obtain the list of the pages the user admins, nor the list of pages they like. So /me/accounts or /me/likes are not useful. I try to obtain all the pages that are added in Facebook, from the last time I visited this url and it suggests them as pages I may like

I am using the example of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ and I take the profile of user I have. So far so good.

I tried to retrieve data using

```
$facebook->api('/me/pages'), 
$facebook->api('/pages'), 
$facebook->api('/pages'), 
$facebook->api('/id=USER_ID/pages')
```

and so on but all of them where wrong or by using Graph API pages?id=USER_ID there were Unsupported get/post request.

As Igy said "Suggested pages is not a feature of the API, only the facebook.com interface"

Something else I tried is to save the url with file_get_contents. As urls I used the

```
ini_set('user_agent','MSIE 4\.0b2;'); //to pretend that I am a browser, it works
http://www.facebook.com/pages?id=USER_ID and
http://www.facebook.com/pages
```

Although the save is done properly, facebook doesn't recognize the authorization and shows the page I want but for users without login.

I tried javascript in Facebook JavaScript Test Console and after logging in it opens the page recognizing authorization. The code is

```
<div id="authResponse"></div>
<script>
var
  div         = document.getElementById('authResponse'),
  showAuthRecord = function(response) {
    if (!response.authResponse) {
      div.innerHTML = '<em>Not Connected</em>';
    } else {
      var html = '<table>';
      for (var key in response.authResponse) {
        html += (
          '<tr>' +
            '<th>' + key + '</th>' +
            '<td>' + response.authResponse[key] + '</td>' +
          '</tr>'
        );
      }
      div.innerHTML = html;
    }
  };
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  showAuthRecord(response);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', showAuthRecord);
});

window.open('https://www.facebook.com/pages','mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this in PHP, or Graph API or FQL Query ? Or add in javascript, code to save the page I open ? I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Why don't you just use the API?

Comment: I used it but it is not recognized, none of /me/pages, /pages, /pages, /id=USER_ID/pages . What do you suggest from API ?

Comment: What are you trying to obtain? the list of the pages the user admins, or the list of pages they like? `/me/accounts` or `/me/likes` - have you looked at the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) documentation?

Comment: None of what you mention. I try to obtain all the pages that are added in Facebook, from the last time I visited this url and it suggests them as pages I may like

Comment: Suggested pages is not a feature of the API, only the facebook.com interface

Comment: Yes, you are right, that why I use file_get_contents and save the page but it doesn't recognize the user. And I don't know how to save in javascript the page instead of opening it in a new window

Comment: I think OP is referring to some form of screen scraping that would analyze the "pages you may like" frontend widget.  If so, this has nothing to do with the `/pages` endpts in the API, which in either case refers to ones directly liked or managed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is **not** possible to obtain through the Facebook Platform. And trying to scrape a page to extract information from is also against Facebook [terms](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms):

> You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise
>   access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots,
>   robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.

Also you cannot ask the users for their password and login information, please refer to the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects
>   Facebook usernames or passwords.

Comment: I agree with you, the fact is that I want to extract information seen only by me, my account only.